# data-bind for Button click function gives error with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I get error of "Unable to parse Binding, ReferenceError: 'calculateTotalPrice' is undefined;
Bindings value: click: calculateTotalPrice

below is my simple code snippet

```
<div style="background-color:black; color:white; overflow:scroll; height:350px;width:300px" id="pricesku">
<span id="total" data-bind="text: totalCost"></span> 
<ul data-bind="foreach: price_quantity" style="list-style-type:none;">
<li>                  
<button data-bind="click: calculateTotalPrice(price)">CLICK THIS TO UPDATE TOTAL</button>                   
</li>             
</ul>
</div>
```

But when I do, click and provide function name, get an error above.

This is my View Modal

function ViewPriceObjectOnWeb(d) {

```
this.price_quantity = ko.observableArray(d);
this.totalCost = ko.observable(100);
this.calculateTotalPrice = function (p) {
var tp = this.totalCost() + p;
//$('#total').text(tp);
}
```

}

and on document ready i make AJAX Call that brings Data from server (this works fine) as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
var sku = "abcd";
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/values?clientSKU=" + sku, //this would give SKU/Price collection as JSON Serialized object from .NET/Server Side
    dataType: "json",
    asyc: false,
    type: "get",
    success: function (msg) {
    var skuandprice = $.parseJSON(msg);          
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewPriceObjectOnWeb(skuandprice), document.getElementById('pricesku'));
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus + '  ' + errorThrown);
    }
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here(i bet i am)? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are inside a `foreach` loop, Knockout expects any functions or properties in the data-bind to be defined within the entries of the array, which in this case are the values in `price_quantity`. To access functions and properties that are defined in the object that holds the array, you use the `$parent` identifier. So to use `calculateTotalPrice` inside your loop, you need to do:

```
<li>                  
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.calculateTotalPrice">CLICK THIS TO UPDATE TOTAL</button>                   
</li>
```

The view model:

```
function ViewPriceObjectOnWeb(d) {
    var self = this;
    self.price_quantity = ko.observableArray(d);
    self.totalCost = ko.observable(100);
    self.calculateTotalPrice = function (p) {
        var tp = self.totalCost() + p;
        self.totalCost(tp);
    };
}
```

Working example (using hard-coded prices): http://jsfiddle.net/jonhopkins/fn7vc/2/

Comment: Jonh can you throw some light (it does not give me error but)       1. Why my SPAN does not get updated with the Price when i click on button to update that(Buttons are in List and any button can be clicked). I would appreciate your help.

Comment: If you haven't changed the code inside `calculateTotalPrice`, then it is because it currently does not update `this.totalCost`. After the first line in the function, add another line `this.totalCost(tp);` and it should update your SPAN

Comment: Jonh, i added this one but still when i click "on Individual Buttons" it does not update SPAN Value. Span Value is updated when Page loads and then never gets updated on Button clicks.

Comment: The problem now is that `this` inside `calculateTotalPrice` is not referring to the `ViewPriceObjectOnWeb` object, but to the function itself. The solution to this is simple, and something that you should get used to doing because it will help a lot with the confusing nature of `this`. Before the line `this.price_quantity = ko.observableArray(d);` add a line `var self = this;` and then change every `this` in the rest of the object to `self`. Updated answer to show how the model should look after the change

Comment: Jonh, yes did that but no RESULT. SPAN is updated on Page Load with some BIG Number. SPAN is not updated when I click on any Buttons in the list (calculateTotalPrice is passing price from data bind).

Comment: Do you mean that you still have `data-bind="click: $parent.calculateTotalPrice(price)"`?

Comment: Yes i have that. function ViewPriceObjectOnWeb(d) {
                var self = this;
                self.price_quantity = ko.observableArray(d);
                self.totalCost = ko.observable(23.24);

                self.calculateTotalPrice = function (p) {
                    //alert(p);
                    var tp = self.totalCost() + p;
                    $('#total').text(tp);
                    self.totalCost(tp);
                }
                
            } and HTML Data bind is <button data-bind="text: price, attr :{  click: $parent.calculateTotalPrice(price)}">GO CAPS</button>

Comment: Take the `(price)` out of the data-bind. It should be `click: $parent.calculateTotalPrice`. If the array `price_quantity` is only an array of numbers, that will work. If each entry in that array is actually another array with a `price` property in it, then also change the `p` in `calculateTotalPrice` to `p.price()`

Comment: then how ON BUTTON CLICK, it would know WHAT TO add to SPAN Text (total). If I click on Button value = 10, it should add 10 to total.

Comment: I know it might not make sense immediately, but Knockout automatically sends the current object to the function being called. And I just tested it with `(price)` still on there and I also got a huge number in the SPAN, but without it, it works for me.

Comment: see this video http://screencast.com/t/gDn7vLUF . Am i doing something wrong yet? Man thx for your patience.

Comment: You're almost there. Instead of `attr` it should be `event`. And inside `calculateTotalPrice` you are still missing the code to update `self.totalCost`. Go to the link in my answer for a working example of how the code should look. And just as a side note, you don't have to manually change the value of the span. Knockout will handle that for you when the value of `totalCost` changes.